# i386 dependencies missing in Pop!_OS for PCSX2 Lutris runner

Tags: pop-os, emulators

I encountered a problem. A few i386 libraries are missing for PCSX2 runner to run in Lutris.
[image: i386 missing dependencies]

Could anyone help me obtaining them, please? What should I do to install them? I found few similar topics on the web but none of them worked unfortunately. Some of them adviced installing standalone PCSX2 emulator but that would defeat a need for having such runner in Lutris on the first place.

Comment: `sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libopengl0:i386` ........ You can find which package to install with `$ apt-file [file]`

Comment: @KnudLarsen Yes, that heped, thank you. Could you, please, make it an answer and I'll accept it as correct?

Comment: @KnudLarsen Although you need `apt-file find [file]` to make it work properly. And of course install apt-file first, if you don't have it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i386 libs not installed: libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0, libEGL.so.1,
> libOpenGL.so.0

You can install the package `apt-file` with apt, and use apt-file to decide a package to install :

```
sudo apt install apt-file 
apt-file update 
apt-file search libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 
apt-file search libEGL.so.1
apt-file search libOpenGL.so.0
```

Or you can use an on-line search to decide a package name :

**1.** *Ubuntu*  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=bionic&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=libEGL.so.1&searchon=contents **..... and .....**  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=bionic&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=libOpenGL.so.0&searchon=contents

**2.** *Debian*  https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0